# How can I hide the Code & State from showing in the address with PHP SDK 3

Tags: facebook, session-state, facebook-php-sdk

How can I hide this "?state=...&code=..." in the address after logging in using php sdk 3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Check for

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
   $user = $facebook->getUser();
   $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
}
```

Facebook returns `userID` only after the login and that code.

Answer (score -1):

You can name a folder "facebook" and put the auth code and probably a session saver or cookie.
Then you can use the session to store the info and proceed on the other sites without getting the state and code parameters in the url.

I think that will work because a norwegian site use this, and it works pretty great.
Good luck :)

- Molty

Answer (score -1):

Facebook will send you code every time user sign up you app or login to your app. So what i do is redirect/reload again

```
        if (isset($_Get['code']) and $_Get['code'] !=''  ){
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();        
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '".APP_URL."';</script>";
        exit;
    }
```

Here APP_URL is something like apps.facebook.com/greatapp/ or you can use Site URL which you set in developer.

Comment: You can put in the the start of the page/php file because the page will redirect so no need to render the whole page.